# Unable to use Bootstrap classes in Reactstrap Navbar component

Tags: bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am using the Reactstrap implementation of Bootstrap 4 on a Node application and trying to render a navbar component using the following JSX:

```
return (
    <Navbar color="inverse" inverse toggleable={`md`} fixed={`top`} className="h-50">
      <NavbarToggler right onClick={this.toggle} />
      <NavbarBrand href="/">reactstrap</NavbarBrand>
      <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
        <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink href="/components/">Components</NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">Github</NavLink>
          </NavItem>
        </Nav>
      </Collapse>
    </Navbar>
);
```

But when the component renders, it skips the class I added (`h-50`) entirely:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse fixed-top">...</nav>
```

The [Reactstrap documentation](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/navbar/) gives a list of props one can use for most of the regular ones such as `navbar-inverse`, `navbar-faded`, etc. but none for custom classes like the one I have. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Just put the value of `className` into `{ ... }`, like this:

```
<Navbar color="inverse" inverse toggleable={`md`} fixed={`top`}
className={"h-50"}>
  ...
</Navbar>
```